# How to Prevent TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars from happening

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy

I am trying to visualise a dataset with matplotlib.

The code is:

```
import time as ti
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import csv
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy.interpolate import * 


data = pd.read_csv("includes\\csv.csv")         
#x = array(data["day"])             
#y = np.array(data["balance"])  
x = float(np.array(data["day"]))
y = float(np.array(data["balance"]))

p1 = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
print(p1)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(x, polyval(p1, x), "-r")
plt.show()
```

The error that accurs is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mittel.py", line 19, in <module>
    x = float(np.array(data["day"]))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am wondering why thats a thing because the csv file i am using is this simple:

```
balance,day

242537,28-5
246362,29-5
246659,30-5
246844,31-5
```

I have been working on this for hours.
Any answers appreciated.

Comment: `float` is a Python function for creating **one** number.  `float(np.array([1,2,3])` raises this error.

Answer (score 1):

Day column in your csv file is having value '28-5','29-5' ....
and np.array(data['day']) will result into a array so you cant cast array to float so getting TypeError.

change line 14-15 to this

`x = [float(day_str.split('-')[0]) for day_str in np.array(data["day"])] 
 y = np.array(data["balance"], dtype=float)`

Comment: Do you want to change all the values balance and days to float?

Comment: yeah, i guess thats what i want

Comment: x = np.array(data["day"], dtype=float) this will do that but in your case day value is '28-5' and in this only 28 is day part rest is month correct?
can you have csv like this 

balance,day

242537,28
246362,29
246659,30
246844,31

Comment: yes the first part is the day and the second the month

Comment: try these lines 
x = [float(day_str.split('-')[0]) for day_str in np.array(data["day"])]
y = np.array(data["balance"], dtype=float)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by formatting it into a n/m/y format.